# Sorting alphabetically regardless of quotes

Tags: mysql

I have a db query and I order it ASC, however, if I have entries that do not start with a letter but with quotes, those results end-up on top.

For example:

> "Battle" of Adams Hill

How do I fix that and have it appear under results that start with B?

Comment: Show your query please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you could just remove all double quotes and then sort, e.g.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY REPLACE(name, '"', '');
```

If you are using MySQL 8+, and want a more surgical way of doing the replacement, you could use `REGEXP_REPLACE` and strip double quotes only from pairs:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY REGEXP_REPLACE(name, '"(.*?)"', '$1');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use TRIM to remove quotes from the field before ordering. TRIM() will remove the first encounter for the quotes, which solves the problem of entries that start with a quote

```
SELECT * FROM your_table ORDER BY TRIM('"' from your_field) ASC;
```